# Question on notation in Mathematical Foundations of Elasticity (Marsden and Hughes)

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, classical-mechanics

I have a small question regarding the usage of notation in this book. It is defining differential forms and their properties in its section, but the $\mid$ operator is being used in a way that I haven't seen before. Of course, I checked their list of notations at the beginning of the book, but I didn't see it there. I'm only interested in item (iv), but I'll give you the rest of the items and the theorem statement so you can see what is going on contextually. For those who own the book, the items are listed on page 106:

[image]

What does the "$\mid$" in "$d(\alpha \mid \mathfrak U) = (d\alpha) \mid \mathfrak U$" mean here? Obviously I've seen the glyph used before, but not in this context. Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A \subset B$ and $f$ is a map defined on $B$ then $f|a$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A.$

Comment: $f|A$, @coffeemath meant.

Comment: Got it. I've seen $\mid$ used in restrictions before but the glyph is also used in probability theory, hence the confusion on seeing it in parenthesis.

Comment: The formulation in (iv) is not completely precise, since the authors only talk about an operator defined on one manifold (and not a "universal" operator defined on any manifold). On could probably replace the last part in (iv) by "and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are forms on $M$ such that $\alpha|_U=\beta|_U$, then $d\alpha|_U=d\beta|_U$". (This is often phrased as "$d$ is a local operator".)